# Sping Batch With Optimistic Locking

Tags: spring-batch

I have a probolem updating the entity with Spring Batch and @Version annotation.
The Stack is Spring Batch + JPA (Hibernate)

The situation is as follows:

```
// Entity
@Entity
class Pocket(
  var count: Int = 0,

  var isUpdated: Boolean = false,
) {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  var id: Long = 0L

  @Version
  var version: Int = 0

}


// Batch Code
@Configuration
class PocketBatch(
  private val jobBuilderFactory: JobBuilderFactory,
  private val stepBuilderFactory: StepBuilderFactory,
  private val emf: EntityManagerFactory,
) {

  @Bean("PocketBatchJob")
  fun job(): Job {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("PocketBatchJob")
      .start(step(1))
      .preventRestart()
      .build()
  }

  @JobScope
  @Bean("PocketBatchStep")
  fun step(
    @Value("#{jobParameters[chunkSize]}") chunkSize: Int,
  ): Step {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("PocketBatchStep")
      .chunk<Pocket, Pocket>(chunkSize)
      .reader(reader(chunkSize))
      .processor(processor())
      .writer(writer())
      .build()
  }

  @StepScope
  @Bean("PocketBatchReader")
  fun reader(
    @Value("#{jobParameters[chunkSize]}") chunkSize: Int,
  ): JpaPagingItemReader<Pocket> {
    return JpaPagingItemReaderBuilder<Pocket>()
      .name("PocketBatchReader")
      .entityManagerFactory(emf)
      .pageSize(chunkSize)
      .queryString("SELECT p FROM Pocket p WHERE p.isUpdated = false")
      .build()
  }

  @StepScope
  @Bean("PocketBatchProcessor")
  fun processor(): ItemProcessor<Pocket, Pocket> {
    return ItemProcessor { item ->
      item.count += 1
      item.isUpdated = true
      item
    }
  }

  @StepScope
  @Bean("PocketBatchWriter")
  fun writer(): JpaItemWriter<Pocket> {
    return JpaItemWriterBuilder<Pocket>()
      .entityManagerFactory(emf)
      .build()
  }

}
```

I understand the issue all pockets will not updated because there's offset in query, but **that's not concern here.**
(Pocket(false) Pocket(false) Pocket(false) -> When chunksize = 1, After one chunk execution DB has Pocket(true) Pocket(false) Pocket(false) and sql has offset 1, so thrid pocket will be chosen while second is skipped.)

**The problem is that "This Batch Job always throws Exception"**
(very simple case : 1 Pocket and chunkSize = 1)

Exception says:
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: update pocket set count=?, is_updated=?, version=? where id=? and version=?

This exception occurs JpaPagingItemReader 195th line (entityManaguer.flush)

I don't know is it itended or bug. Looking for help from someone with similar experience.

Thank you, Have a good day :)

Comment: Is this the same as https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1826?

Comment: Thank you for you answer!
Yes, I understand it is very similar problem (I think it's 'similar' because my concren was not multi-threading. I tested in zero configuration)

I also read your comment here
(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/pull/591#issuecomment-805046582) and I totally agree with "the current implementation of a chunk-oriented step is not friendly to concurrent access. The current model tries to lock access to shared state in memory by using a semaphore coupled with an optimistic locking strategy at the job repository level".
So I know it's difficult problem.

Comment: In fact, additionally, I can avoid this problem if I change the reader, processor, wrtier return type.

Instaed using entity class directly, Reader<Pocket> -> Processor<Pocket, Pocket> -> Writer<Pocket>,
I can use the entity primary key (Long type), Reader<Long> -> Writer<Long> and read Pocket in Wrtier and process.

This works because pocket is not mangned by EntityManager in reader.

I want to know it's intended by Spring-Batch Team or it's planned to fix. Thank you very much :)

Comment: No, there is no plan to fix the issue in the current implementation. You can always merge that PR in a fork if it works for you, I have seen some users doing it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1826#issuecomment-1000218381. Please check and follow https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3950 for more details and updates about the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.transacted(false)` in your `itemReader`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).